# Suggested edit did not show in review queue

Tags: bug, editing, review

Today I checked the [review page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review) and noticed there are no items. Cool.

Then I browsed [a question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14760/stepdaughter-trouble), just to see this:

> [image]

Puzzled, I checked the review again, went to https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits and got the familiar "There are no items for you to review" message.

I clicked the "edit" in the question itself, and got the proper dialog:

> [image]

Approved the edit and now it's all good and recorded as a review, but it did not show in the suggested edits queue, so I wonder how many other edits we miss here?

I have full edit privilege here, and was able to see suggested edits in the queue before.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you're running into a [new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238897/166646) just added to the edit review queues:

> As of [late last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039), we're now giving suggested-edit reviewers a limited period of exclusivity. What this means:
>
> - When you view a pending suggested edit, the system will avoid assigning that edit to any other reviewers until you've submitted your review or a reasonable period of time (currently 3 minutes) has passed. The number of "in review" tasks is tracked, and the main /review page updates the counts accordingly.
> - We don't actually *block* multiple reviewers, so if you open the suggested edit from the question page (rather than being assigned it by the system via /review) you'll be given the opportunity to review it regardless of who else currently has it open.
> - If you don't explicitly take action on a review (approve / reject / improve / skip), it won't be assigned to anyone else (or appear in the counts shown under /review) until your period of exclusivity expires.
>
> Note that while this behavior is new to suggested edits, it isn't new to review - single-review tasks (first posts / late answers) have had this behavior for a while.

Comment: Might be, but it's really not good to lock it for hours or days so likely it's still buggy. Anna Lear said she pinged some folks in the team, let's see what will come of this. :)